# Consulta recursiva en PSQL

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql

Tengo una tabla llamada "muertes" con dos columnas. Una es una fecha, y la otra es la cantidad de personas que han muerto en esa fecha.
Necesito una consulta que sume la cantidad de personas que han muerto los últimos 90 días para cada día dentro de la tabla.

Lo que tengo hasta ahora es algo de esta forma:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "fecha", 
(SELECT SUM(cantidad) FROM deaths WHERE 
"fecha" <= deaths."fecha" AND "fecha" >= deaths."fecha" - INTERVAL '90 day')
AS tot_deaths FROM deaths;;
```

Ejemplo de tabla "muertes":

```
   fecha    | cantidad
------------+----------
 2021-02-10 |       13
 2021-01-10 |       24
 2021-09-30 |        3
 2021-10-02 |        3
 2021-10-01 |       34
 2013-10-01 |       32
```

Resultado erróneo que obtengo con la consulta:

```
   fecha    | tot_deaths
------------+------------
 2021-01-10 |        109
 2021-10-02 |        109
 2021-02-10 |        109
 2021-09-30 |        109
 2021-10-01 |        109
 2013-10-01 |        109
```

Comment: Saludos. Usa `GROUP BY`; adicionalmente usa como fecha de fin la función que te devuelva el dia de **hoy** y como fecha de inicio **hoy** menos 90 días.

Comment: Si no me equivoco, esto solamente calcularía la cantidad de muertes de hace 90 días para hoy. Lo que necesito es que, para cada fecha dentro de la columna, se calcule esto. Entonces, para ayer, tendría que saber la fecha de hace 91 días y calcular entre 91 días y ayer.

Comment: Saludos de nuevo; usa alias; que sean distinto de tu SQL principal y el subquery; esto dato que el SQL principal y SubQuery estan usando la misma tabla.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tus comentarios Roberto, pero los cambios que sugieres no me dan el resultado esperado. ¿Quizás estoy haciendo algo mal? Agradecería que fueras más explícito si es posible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para calcular el total de muertes de los últimos 90 días para cada una de las fechas de la tabla tienes que hacer un `INNER JOIN` con las misma tabla (utilizando como condición un rango de 90 días para las fechas), luego agrupar por la fecha de la primer tabla y sumar las cantidades de la segunda tabla:

```
SELECT d1.fecha, SUM(d2.cantidad) AS muertes_acunuladas
FROM deaths d1
INNER JOIN deaths d2 ON d2.fecha BETWEEN (d1.fecha - INTERVAL '90 day') AND d1.fecha
GROUP BY d1.fecha
ORDER BY d1.fecha;
```

Salida con los datos de ejemplo de la pregunta:

| fecha | muertes_acunuladas |
| --- | --- |
| 2013-10-01 | 32 |
| 2021-01-10 | 24 |
| 2021-02-10 | 37 |
| 2021-09-30 | 3 |
| 2021-10-01 | 37 |
| 2021-10-02 | 40 |

Modificando tu consulta original, sería algo así:

```
SELECT d1.fecha, (SELECT SUM(d2.cantidad) 
                  FROM deaths d2
                  WHERE d2.fecha BETWEEN (d1.fecha - INTERVAL '90 day') AND d1.fecha) AS tot_deaths 
FROM deaths AS d1
ORDER BY d1.fecha;
```

Tienes que usar un alias para la tabla, para poder especificar a que tabla pertenece la columna que estás referenciando.